# What is OPTIL? (.Net framework history)

Tags: c#, .net, legacy, .net-1.1

There is [`MethodImplAttributes.OPTIL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodimplattributes?view=net-7.0).

```
OPTIL   2
Specifies that the method implementation is in Optimized Intermediate Language (OPTIL).
```

What this story was about? Has this ever been implemented?

Comment: I think, when you add that enum to a MethodImpl attribute, you're asking the compiler to optimize that method for performance. However, I think exactly what/how something is optimized depends on the implementation of the compiler. I believe this is mainly a *hint* to the compiler, and whether or not the compiler does additional optimizations depends on the compiler.

Comment: However, I'm not very familiar with this, so take my comment with a grain of salt ;)

Comment: It is archeological, going back to the .net 1.0 release.  They had an alternate format for IL available, with a dedicated jitter (mscorojt.dll), a subset of the IL we use today.  Probably meant to create smaller assemblies.  Very obscure, it didn't go anywhere.